# Possible to change a Google Cloud Platform Project ID?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I understand project names can be changed however I don't see any method to change the project ID.

Is this possible using the gcloud shell perhaps if not in the UI?

Comment: technically speaking, changing the ID would mean it's a new project...

Comment: I looked into creating a new project with the correct name/ID then moving the instances/disks there. This doesn't seem possible though, any move as far as I can tell is between zones within a project - never to different projects. If I can't change an existing project's ID and I can't move things between projects, is it just stuck as is?

Comment: You can move (with great pain) resource between projects. There are a few methods, and they could all be helpful or not depending on your situation, simply search online and you'll find more than one detailed guide. Personally, with instances, I create images of the instances (or snapshots and then images if the machines can't be turned off) which are natively accessible from any other project **within my organisation** on GCP.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cannot change project ID.

You have an option to use a custom domain, e.g. www.myCompany.com, in which case projectID is something that only your internal code needs to know.

Comment: Ok, thanks for validating this, greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Project ID`(s) not being able to be changed can impact your project by blocking some functionality, future or current, i.e at the time of writing, you cannot use HTTP triggers for *Cloud Functions* on the GCP platform if your project ID includes a colon:
*"HTTP trigger type not available for `project ID`(s) containing the colon character."* ([GCP Documentation 1](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http); [GCP Documentation 2](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/filesystem#deploy_using_the_gcloud_tool))